# R : Portfolio Optimization - solve.QP / Constraints are inconsistent, no solution

Tags: r

I am trying to use solve.QP to solve a portfolio optimization problem(quadratic).

There are 4 assets, and constraints are as follows:

1. Sum of weights = 1
2. Portfolio’s expected return >= 2%
3. Each asset weight greater than 0. (No shortsale allowed)
4. Each asset weight smaller than 0.5.

“Constituents” are monthly (59 months) return table for 4 stocks.

```
CR_DMAT = cov(constituents)
ER_DVEC <- matrix (apply(constituents, 2, mean))

A.Equality <- matrix(c(1,1,1,1,), ncol=1)
AMAT <- cbind(A.Equality, ER_DVEC, diag(4), -diag(4))

BVEC <- c(1, 2.0, rep(0,4), rep(-0.5,4))

qp <- solve.QP(CR_DMAT, ER_DVEC, AMAT, BVEC, meq=1)
qp$solution
```

Even though, I founded optimized weights for each asset by EXCEL,
But R says that “constraints are inconsistent, no solution!”

Is there any problems?